# Custom ConnectionField in graphene

Tags: relay, graphene-python

I'm not understanding how to use custom fields in a ConnectionField in graphene. I have something like:

```
class ShipConnection(Connection):
    extra = String()

    class Meta:
        node = Ship

SHIPS = ['Tug boat', 'Row boat', 'Canoe']

class Query(AbstractType):
    ships = relay.ConnectionField(ShipConnection)

    def resolve_ships(self, args, context, info):
        return ShipConnection(
            extra='Some extra text',
            edges=???
        )
```

Normally, you'd say:

```
    def resolve_ships(self, args, context, info):
        return SHIPS
```

but how do you return something in extra *and* return a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to do this is *exactly* explained [here](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/issues/592).

```py
class Ship(graphene.ObjectType):
    ship_type = String()

    def resolve_ship_type(self, info):
         return self.ship_type

    class Meta:
          interfaces = (Node,)

class ShipConnection(Connection):
    total_count = Int() # i've found count on connections very useful! 

    def resolve_total_count(self, info):
        return get_count_of_all_ships()

    class Meta:
        node = Ship

    class Edge:
        other = String()
        def resolve_other(self, info):
            return "This is other: " + self.node.other

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    ships = relay.ConnectionField(ShipConnection)

    def resolve_ships(self, info):
        return get_list_of_ships_from_database_or_something_idk_its_your_implmentation()

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
```

---

I don't know if this is recommended, but the `resolve_total_count` method can also be implemented as:

```
def resolve_total_count(self, info):
    return len(self.iterable)
```

I don't know if the `iterable` property is documented anywhere, but I was able to find it while investigating the `Connection` class

Answer (score 4):

The answer turns out to be to use an undocumented class method of graphene's `ConnectionField` class, called `resolve_connection`. The following works:

```
def resolve_ships(self, args, context, info):
    field = relay.ConnectionField.resolve_connection(
        ShipConnection,
        args,
        SHIPS
    )

    field.extra = 'Whatever'
    return field
```